# Google Play Services Nearby registration failed with TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-pendingintent, google-nearby

On my application on login we're registering for Google Play Services nearby and on logout un-registering (code below). Even during registration, we're always first unsubscribing, before subscribing.

But after a few logout/login cycle the app keeps catching ApiException with the message [ApiException: 2801: Will exceed MAX_PENDING_INTENTS_PER_APP=5](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/NearbyMessagesStatusCodes.html?hl=pl#TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS)

I know what the error means, but as far as I'm aware the code is unregistering first. So it shouldn't have reach that quota.

Subscribe code, run on-login and when beacons get updated

```
    val nearby = Nearby.getMessagesClient(app, MessagesOptions.Builder()
            .setPermissions(NearbyPermissions.BLE)
            .build())
    val task = apis
        .checkApiAvailability(nearby)
        .onSuccessTask { nearby.unsubscribe(BeaconReceiver.generatePendingIntent(app)) }
        .onSuccessTask {
            return@onSuccessTask if (beacons.isEmpty()) {
                // if beacons is empty, I don't have to register anything,
                Tasks.forResult(null as Void?)
            } else {
                val messageFilter = MessageFilter.Builder()
                beacons.forEach {
                    messageFilter.includeIBeaconIds(it.proximityUuid, it.major, it.minor)
                }

                val options = SubscribeOptions.Builder()
                    .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
                    .setFilter(messageFilter.build())
                    .build()

                nearby.subscribe(BeaconReceiver.generatePendingIntent(app), options)
            }
        }
    // inside awaitResult there's Task.await, and catch/log exceptions
    val result = awaitResult("Beacon", 30, task)
```

Unsubscribe code, run on every logout, almost the same as subscribe

```
    val nearby = Nearby.getMessagesClient(app, MessagesOptions.Builder()
        .setPermissions(NearbyPermissions.BLE)
        .build())
    val geofence = GeofencingClient(app)
    val task = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().checkApiAvailability(nearby, geofence)
        .onSuccessTask { nearby.unsubscribe(BeaconReceiver.generatePendingIntent(app)) }
        .onSuccessTask { geofence.removeGeofences(GeofenceReceiver.generatePendingIntent(app)) }
    val result = awaitResult("SdkDisabled", 30, task)
```

and the PendingIntent code, it uses our explicit class and a static request code:

```
val intent = Intent(context, BeaconReceiver::class.java)
return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, BEACON_REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
```

**So question:**

Why it's throwing exception and what can I do to properly unregister/unsubscribe?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious. But try this: remove the `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT' on the call to `getBroadcast()` when you unsubscribe.

Comment: Is there a reason you are calling `subscribe()` with `PendingIntent` instead of using a listener?

Comment: @DavidWasser yes. Because I'm doing background scanning. Even if the app dies, play services still let's us know about it.

Comment: @DavidWasser I'll give a try on the flag thing

Comment: hey@DavidWasser nice catch! I finally got around to it and works. If you want to write it as an answer so I can mark it as correct. Also, maybe care to explain why the flag interferes with the subscription process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` on the call to `getBroadcast()` when you unsubscribe.

When you unsubscribe, you need to provide a `PendingIntent` that "matches" the one you used to subscribe. By using `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` you are canceling the existing `PendingIntent` and creating a new one and obvioulsy the new one does not "match" the one you used when you subscribed.

IMHO this is a bug in the Play Services library, because it isn't using the correct "matching" algorithm, because the `PendingIntent`s should "match".